# Send data to database from FROM in wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, forms

I created a simple tool for "reviews". Inserting the content of the function or plugin including the form is using a shortcode.

Displaying the data from the database works when I manually insert it in, but if I want to submit the data from the form, after submitting the data is written to the database and the page redirects to the "This page does not exist 404" page.

I don't understand why, when it is included via include directly in the submit script with the data written to the database.

## **index.php:**

```
// funkce, která vytvoří tabulku wp_reviews v databázi
function create_reviews_table() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'reviews';

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        rating int NOT NULL,
        description text NOT NULL,
        image varchar(255),
        created_at datetime NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}

// zavoláme funkci create_reviews_table() při aktivaci pluginu
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_reviews_table');



function my_enqueue() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', plugins_url( 'js/script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', plugins_url( 'css/style.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );


function wp_reviews_shortcode() {
  ob_start();

  if (isset($_POST['submit_review'])) {
    submit_review();
  }
  ?>
  <div class="my-wrapper">
    <div class="w30">
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit_my_review'])) {
                  submit_review();
                }
            ?>
        <?php include 'form.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'submit-review.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="w70">
        <?php include 'reviews-list.php'; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php

  return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('wp_reviews', 'wp_reviews_shortcode');

?>
```

## **form.php:**

```
<div class="wp-reviews-form">
  <h2>Napsat recenzi</h2>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div>
      <label for="name">Jméno a příjmení:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="rating">Hodnocení spolurpáce:</label>
      <select name="rating" required>
        <option value="">-- Vyberte hodnocení --</option>
        <option value="1">Hrozná</option>
        <option value="2">Ucházející</option>
        <option value="3">Dobrá</option>
        <option value="4">Super</option>
        <option value="5">Úžasná</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="description">Popis recenze:</label>
      <textarea name="description" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="image">Nahrát obrázek:</label>
      <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit_my_review" value="Odeslat recenzi">
    </div>
      
  </form>
</div>
```

## **submit-review.php:**

```
<?php

function submit_review() {
  if (isset($_POST['submit_my_review'])) {
    require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
    global $wpdb;

    $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']);
    $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
    $rating = intval($_POST['rating']);
    $description = sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['description']);

    $image_url = '';
    if ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {
      $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['image']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
      if (isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
        wp_die('Nepodařilo se nahrát obrázek: ' . $upload['error']);
      } else {
        $image_url = $upload['url'];
      }
    }
    
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'reviews'; 
      
    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'rating' => $rating,
        'description' => $description,
        'image' => $image_url,
        'created_at' => current_time('mysql')
      ),
      array('%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s')
    );

    echo 'Review submitted successfully';

    wp_die();

  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you may have an issue with your shortcode, as it is a really messy:

```
function wp_reviews_shortcode() {
ob_start();

  if (isset($_POST['submit_review'])) {
    submit_review();
  }
  ?>
  <div class="my-wrapper">
    <div class="w30">
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit_my_review'])) {
                  submit_review();
                }
            ?>
        <?php include 'form.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'submit-review.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="w70">
        <?php include 'reviews-list.php'; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php

  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

You run submit_review() function twice, but actually once, because you do not have "submit_review" in your form, so first if can be removed.

Second thing, your both calls are before the function is declared, because you include submit-review.php later. And you do all of this inside buffer.

Also, there is no need to call submit function inside HTML.

So you can change this code to:

```
function wp_reviews_shortcode() {

  include 'submit-review.php';

  if (isset($_POST['submit_my_review'])) {
      submit_review();
  }

  ob_start();
  ?>
  <div class="my-wrapper">
    <div class="w30">
        <?php include 'form.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="w70">
        <?php include 'reviews-list.php'; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php

  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Also, to be sure, you can add an action parameter to  the tag to explicitly tell the code to call the same page, like that:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```